# How to know when all physics bodies have stopped moving in Cocos2d V3.0 with Chipmunk

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

The only way I can think to do it is to check velocities for all physics bodies during every collisions.

```
- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair piece:(CCNode *)pieceA piece:(CCNode *)pieceB{

    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < [[_physicsWorld children] count]; i++) {

        x = x + [[[_physicsWorld children][i] physicsBody] velocity].x;
        y = y + [[[_physicsWorld children][i] physicsBody] velocity].y;
    }

    if ( x == 0 && y == 0 ) {
        NSLog(@"stopped");
    }

    return YES;

}
```

This logs “stopped” multiple times when the scene first loads, then doesn’t log “stopped” again, even after physics bodies have clearly started moving and colliding and then come to a stop.

Ideally I'd like a delegate method that would notify me when all physics bodies have stopped moving, but I can't seem to find one.

FYI: I'm using the standard Chipmunk physics engine that's baked into Cocos2d V3.0

Answer (score 1):

Chipmunk has a internal mechanism, which can, if activated, automatically deactivate physics bodies. My approach (I am using cocos2dx 3.11.1 and not -obj version with chipmunk 7.0.1) is:

1. activate the chipmunk idle mechanism (0.5 second - meaning, if an object is not moving for longer than 0.5 second it will be deactivated):

   ```
   cpSpaceSetSleepTimeThreshold(space, 0.5f);
   ```

You do not need to use

```
    cpSpaceSetIdleSpeedThreshold(space, <speed>);
```

because chipmunk calculates the threshold speed for you (according the gravitation used).

2. use this code for determination if all objects are not moving (static and kinetic bodies never sleep):

   ```
   bool isAnyPhysicsBodyMoving(){
       int i = 0; bool isMoving = false;
       const Vector<PhysicsBody*>& bodies = getPhysicsWorld()->getAllBodies();
       while( i < bodies.size() && !isMoving){
          PhysicsBody *body = bodies.at(i);
          isMoving =    cpBodyGetType(body->getCPBody()) == CP_BODY_TYPE_DYNAMIC 
                     && !body->isResting();
          i++;
       }
       return isMoving;
   }
   ```
3. use static (and not kinetic) body for walls, in order to let objects sleep:

   ```
   // wall
   Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
   Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
   float border = 10.0f;
   Size wallBodySize = Size(visibleSize.width+2*border, visibleSize.height+2*border);
   PhysicsBody *wallBody = PhysicsBody::createEdgeBox(wallBodySize, PhysicsMaterial(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f), border);
   Node* wall = Node::create();
   wall->addComponent(wallBody);
   wall->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.5f, 0.5f));
   wall->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width/2+origin.x, visibleSize.height/2+origin.y));

   cpVect tt;
   tt.x = wall->getPosition().x; tt.y = wall->getPosition().y;
   //set position manually and BEFORE adding the object into the space
   cpBodySetPosition(wallBody->getCPBody(), tt);
   cpBodySetType(wallBody->getCPBody(), CP_BODY_TYPE_STATIC);
   addChild(wall);
   ```

Any dynamic body connected to a kinetic body (for example laying on) will never sleep.

4. test it with DEBUG activated

   ```
   getPhysicsWorld()->setDebugDrawMask(PhysicsWorld::DEBUGDRAW_ALL);
   ```

the boxes (their content) must become grey (=sleeping) and not red (=active):
[image]

In order to let it work, I have:

1. added an access method (to get cpSpace) in CCPhysicsWorld.h:

   ```
    inline cpSpace* getSpace() const { return _cpSpace; }
   ```
2. Fix call of

   ```
    cpBodySetTorque(body, 0.0f);`
   ```

   in CCPhysicsBody.cpp to

   ```
    if (body->t != 0.0f){
       cpBodySetTorque(body, 0.0f);
    }
   ```
3. Fix call of

   ```
    cpBodySetPosition(_cpBody, tt);`
   ```

   in CCPhysicsBody.cpp to

   ```
    if (!cpveql(tt, cpBodyGetPosition(_cpBody))){
        cpBodySetPosition(_cpBody, tt);
    }
   ```

Steps 2. and 3. are necessary to avoid setting of the same physics body properties, which wake up a sleeping body.

The advantage of this approach is, that the chipmunk does not make any calculations for such physical bodies - saving CPU and battery.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works.

**tl;dr**

The basic idea is to keep track of the positions of the sprites myself, and then periodically check them to see if any of them have moved since they were last checked.

**Longer version**

I created a subclass of CCNode with the class name `Piece`.

These are my objects that are added to the physics world.

```
@implementation Piece {

    float _previousX;
    float _previousY;
}

-(void)updatePreviousScreenXandY{

    _previousX = self.position.x;
    _previousY = self.position.y;
}

-(BOOL)hasntMoved{

    float currentX = self.position.x;
    float currentY = self.position.y;

    if ( currentX == _previousX && currentY == _previousY ) {
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

This is in my CCNode that acts as the game scene

```
-(void)doStuffAfterPiecesStopMoving:(NSTimer*)timer{


    BOOL noPiecesHaveMoved = TRUE;

    for (int i = 0;  i < [[_physicsWorld children] count]; i++) {
        if ( [[_physicsWorld children][i] hasntMoved] == FALSE ) {
            noPiecesHaveMoved = FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( noPiecesHaveMoved ) {
        [timer invalidate];
        NSLog(“Pieces have stopped moving”);
    }else{
        NSLog(“Pieces are still moving”);
        [self updateAllPreviousPiecePositions];
    }

}

-(void)updateAllPreviousPiecePositions{

    for (int i=0; i < [[_physicsWorld children] count]; i++) {
        Piece *piece = (Piece*)[_physicsWorld children][i];
        [piece updatePreviousScreenXandY];
    }

}
```

All I have to do is

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIME_BETWEEN_CHECKS
                                 target:_gamePlay
                               selector:@selector(doStuffAfterPiecesStopMoving:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

and it’ll run whatever code I want after all Piece nodes have stopped moving.

The key to getting it to work well is to get the values for the Chipmunk space’s sleepTimeThreshold and the timer above’s time as low as possible.

My experimenting suggests the following settings work okay, but anything lower will cause problems (i.e. collisions not taking place properly):

sleepTimeThreshold = 0.15

my timer = 0.05

**If anyone has a different/better solution or improvements to the above code, please post.**